# Exist in vb.net a new list with two arguments?

Tags: vb.net

I want to use a list with two parameters like this but my vb display error:

```
Dim test As New List(Of String, Date)
```

I want to insert to parameters in a list and after i want to reader this parameters. If have a new list i would proceed like this:

```
Dim test As New List(Of String, Date)

test.add("Popescu bogdan", "21/02/2017")
```

I would like an example with a list with two parameters like and example and after to reader this two parameters. Is possible with collection or another method?

Comment: I think Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)  would be more suitable then no? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Mederic It's not at all the same thing. Dictionary doesn't guarantee the index order or do lookups the same way.

Comment: What version of .Net/Visual Studio? VS2017 has some nice new stuff that makes this easier.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn he never mentionned indexing so dictionnary could be viable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using List(Of T)

The approach of using a List is good and you then have two sub solutions.

- Creating your own class
- Using Tuple (check documentation as new features are available in 2017)

The ideal solution would be working with a class for instance:

```
Public Class TimedEvent
    Public Property EventName As String
    Public Property EventTime As Date
End Class
```

Then Use:

```
Dim test As New List(Of TimedEvent)
```

For Tuple simply use:

```
Dim test As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Date))()
test.Add(New Tuple(Of String, Date)("Popescu bogdan", "21/02/2017"))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

### Using Dictionary

I think you could use `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`

Note: Dictionary won't let you use the same keys so the string should always be different
In your case you could use:

```
Dim test As New Dictionary(Of String, Date)
test.Add("Popescu bogdan", "21/02/2017")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dictionary of course wouldn't allow multiple keys with the same name.

Comment: @Magnus yeah i'll add it

Comment: Tuples go back much farther than 2017.  I believe there is more support for them in more recent versions of Visual Studio/VB, but the code shown would work with VS 2013 (if not older).

Answer (score 4):

Try a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, DateTime))`

```
Dim test As New List(Of String, DateTime)
test.Add(New Tuple(Of String, DateTime)("Popescu bogdan", "21/02/2017"))
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2017, there are some shortcuts you can take to make this even easier to work with, and you can use `ValueTuple`, which has some nice advantages:

```
Dim test As New List(Of (String, DateTime))
test.Add( ("Popescu bogdan", #21/02/2017#) )
```

A final option is to use a class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Property AString() As String
    Public Property ADateTime() As DateTime
End Class

Dim test As New List(Of MyClass)
test.Add(New MyClass() With { .AString = "Popescu bogdan", .ADateTime = #21/02/2017# })
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i put more than one in tuple how read individual, date and string?

Answer (score 3):

A tuple would work but you could also start creating classes for your data.

```
Class Information

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property [Date] As DateTime

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal [date] As DateTime)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Date = [date]
    End Sub

End Class

Sub Main()

    Dim test As New List(Of Information)

    test.Add(New Information("Popescu bogdan", DateTime.Parse("21/02/2017")))

End Sub
```